# Including new app causing AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' in Python/Django app

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.9 I'm getting the following error when I try in include an app I am developing within my INSTALLED_APS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1180, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_long_column_names())
  File "/var/www/cltc/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1631, in _check_long_column_names
    for m2m in f.remote_field.through._meta.local_fields:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

This is, I believe being caused by something wrong in models.py which looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
import datetime

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Category', max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField('Member age at start of Subscription', default=18)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Subscription', max_length=30)
    cost = models.DecimalField('Price', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    start = models.DateField('Start Date')
    end = models.DateField('End Date')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        through         = 'SubscritptionCategory',
        related_name    = 'category',
        verbose_name    = 'Membership Category',
        help_text       = 'Membership Categories included in the Subscription'
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

    def clean (self):
        if self.start > self.end:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Start Date must be earlier than End Date"),
                )

    def is_live(self):
        if self.end >= datetime.datetime.now().date():
            return True
        else:
            return False

class SubscriptionCategory (models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(
        Subscription,
        verbose_name    = 'Subscription',
        help_text       = 'A class of membership (which could include several members, eg Family).',
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        verbose_name    = 'Category',
        help_text       = 'A class of member (eg adult)',
    )
```

Any help most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your declaration of the `through` attribute of Subscription.category: "SubscritptionCategory" rather than "SubscriptionCategory". Because of that, Django can't find the model you're referencing.

Note however that since you don't define any extra fields on that through model, there's not much point having it; your code would be simpler, and many of Django's functions would work better, if you didn't define it.

Comment: Two hours and I couldn't see that!  Thank you